# DropzoneJS does not "attach" properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dropzone.js

It's quite difficult for me to explain whats going wrong, but i'll do my best.
My website has been using dropzone for over a year now, it ran perfectly without me ever having to update the files. However since last week it suddenly stopped working.

The only thing i can link to this is the fact that my Firefox browser updated from version 29.0.1 to 30.0, however IE, Chrome, Safari stopped working aswell so... weird.

I tried lots of different things trying to get it to work again, and still it seems to fail very single time! I tried updating the files, i tried diffrent initialization options, from hardcoded javascript form inserts, to the official jquery creation method, nothing.

When i use the jquery method als listed below i, the div stays empty.

```
$("#test").dropzone({ url: "my/action-page.php" });
```

So next thing i went back to the complete basics, a single html file, where i include the dropzone.js and jquery library.

I created a div with id #test, and with a document ready function tried loading the dropzone... nothing. When i use my hardcode javascript form with fallback method, that gets displayed, so it seems that something is working, but i really cannot figure out whats wrong.

Here is my full test page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="x">
        <meta name="keywords" content="x">
        <meta name="author" content="x">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="dropzone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {               
                /*content = '<form action="my/action-page.php" method="post" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
                    content += '<div class="fallback">';
                        content += '<input name="file" type="file" />';
                        content += '<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />';
                    content += '</div>';
                content += '</form>';
                $("#test").html(content);*/

                $("#test").dropzone({ url: "modules/projects/workLetter.php?action=uploadWorkLetter&projectID=1" });
            });

            function test()
            {
                $("#test").dropzone({ url: "modules/projects/workLetter.php?action=uploadWorkLetter&projectID=1" });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="test();">Reload with javascript</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use any kind of version control repository? I'd try to revert changes to a working version and then check what kind of changes broke it

Comment: We don't, however nothing on the website got changed for about 2 weeks, the malfunctioning pretty much came from nowhere.

Comment: Well i found the problem, took me ages since i didn't get any error.
I had a form inside my template which saves the general data, i changed that and now it's all working again.

However i still find it strange how that did not cause problems before, but does now!